# Scala array understanding?

Tags: scala

I have tried below array example in my scala console.Declared immutable array, tried to change the array index values.Immutable should not allow modifying the values. I don't understand whats happening .can anyone explain, please.

```
val numbers=Array(1,2,3)
numbers(0)=5
print numbers
res1: Array[Int] = Array(5, 2, 3)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why no immutable arrays in scala standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825702/why-no-immutable-arrays-in-scala-standard-library)

Comment: Because the default array is the same as Java's array, which is mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring something as a `val` does not make it immutable. It merely prevents reassignment. For example, the following code would not compile:

```
val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3)
numbers = Array(5, 2, 3)
```

Notice that what changes in the above code is not something about the array object's internal state: what changes is the array that the name `numbers` references. At the first line, the name `numbers` refers to the array `Array(1, 2, 3)`, but in the second line we try reassign the name `numbers` to the array `Array(5, 2, 3)` (which the compiler won't allow, since the name `numbers` is declared using `val`).

In contrast, the below code is allowed:

```
val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3)
numbers(0) = 5
```

In this code, the name `numbers` still points to the same array, but it's the internal state of the array that has changed. Using the `val` keyword for the name of an object cannot prevent that object's internal state from changing, the `val` keyword can only prevent the name from being reassigned to some other object.

Answer (score 2):

You did not declare an immutable array.  `Array` in Scala is mutable.

Where you might be confused is what exactly `val` vs `var` means.  `val` does not make an object immutable, it makes the reference immutable so you can't reassign a different array to your variable, but you can still modify the contents since it is a mutable object.

If you want immutability you need to use `val` together with an immutable object like `Vector` or `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your understanding of scala Array is not right.

> **Please pay attention to the following principle!**

Arrays preserve order, can contain duplicates, and are mutable.

```
scala> val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
numbers: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> numbers(3) = 10
```

Lists preserve order, can contain duplicates, and are immutable.

```
scala> val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
numbers: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> numbers(3) = 10
<console>:9: error: value update is not a member of List[Int]
              numbers(3) = 10
```