# How to update a specific element in Immutable Array using Scala

Tags: scala

I have immutable array in scala as below:

```
val myArray = Array.fill(3)(null)
```

So what I want is that updating some location in the array.
Such as a second location. I tried this way but it is always only returning an array of one value

```
myArray(0) = "2"

myArray(1) = "3"
```

It is only returning first element for some reasons which is "2" .

Answer (score 4):

Arrays in Scala are mutable.

```scala
val myArray = Array.fill[String](3)(null)
// myArray is Array(null, null, null)

myArray(1) = "1"

// myArray is now Array(null, 1, null)
```

---

If you want an immutable replacement for the `Array`, look at the [`Vector`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html):

```scala
val myVec = Vector.fill[String](3)(null)
// myVec is Vector(null, null, null)

myVec.updated(1, "1")  // returns NEW Vector(null, 1, null)

// here myVec is still Vector(null, null, null)
```

Note, that updating `Vector` is slower than mutating the `Array`, that is the price of immutability.

---

Another alternative is to use an immutable [`ArraySeq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ArraySeq.html) in (scala 2.13):

```scala
val myArrSeq = ArraySeq.fill[String](3)(null)
// myArrSeq is ArraySeq(null, null, null)

myArrSeq.updated(1, "1")  // returns NEW ArraySeq(null, 1, null)

// myArrSeq is still ArraySeq(null, null, null)
```

It behaves the same way as Vector does, and is backed by plain array internally, but, **(important!)**, each update copies the whole sequence ( O(N) ), which is not acceptable in most scenarios.

---

Also, check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825702/why-no-immutable-arrays-in-scala-standard-library).