# ArrayBuffer elements are not being swapped in Scala

Tags: scala, permutation, swap

The below is the Scala Code for finding the permutations of the given digits using the Johnson-Trotter algorithm:-

```
 import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

 object Code{

    def factorial(x:Int):Int={
        if(x==0) return 1 else x*factorial(x-1)
    }

    def permutation(arr:ArrayBuffer[Int]):ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Int]]={
        val len=arr.length;
        var result=new ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Int]]

        for(i<-Range(0,factorial(len)/len,1)){
            if(i%2==0){
                for(j<-Range(len-1,0,-1)){
                    var c=arr(j)
                    arr(j)=arr(j-1)
                    arr(j-1)=c
                    result.append(arr)
                }
                var c=arr(len-1)
                arr(len-1)=arr(len-2)
                arr(len-2)=c
                result.append(arr)
            }
            else{
                for(j<-Range(0,len-1,1)){
                    var c=arr(j)
                    arr(j)=arr(j+1)
                    arr(j+1)=c
                    result.append(arr)
                }
                var c=arr(0)
                arr(0)=arr(1)
                arr(1)=c
                result.append(arr)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
        var arr=ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)
        var perm=permutation(arr)
        for(j<-Range(0,perm.length,1)){
            for(k<-Range(0,perm(0).length,1)){
                println(" "+perm(j)(k))
            }
            println()
        }      
    }
}
```

But, the resultant two dimensional ArrayBuffer contains (1,2,3) six times for the ArrayBuffer input of (1,2,3) instead of showing all the permutations. I believe that the elements are not being swapped. What am I doing wrong here ? Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` (same as `ArrayBuffer`) in scala is mutable. When you do `result.append(arr)`, you're adding the references to the same array to the `result`. When `arr` is then modified,  the modification can be observed in all elements of the `result`.

One way to fix your code is to replace all instances of `result.append(arr)` with `result.append(arr.clone())`.

That is correct, but not very efficient. Another, slightly more efficient approach would be to use `Vector[Int]` instead of `ArrayBuffer`, which is immutable and uses structural sharing to perform more efficient updates.

See also [How to update a specific element in Immutable Array using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578656/how-to-update-a-specific-element-in-immutable-array-using-scala/69578722#69578722)